# 'CourseTake' object has no attribute 'points'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
credit_hours = models.IntegerField()
instructor = models.ForeignKey(Instructor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='course')
def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.title



class CourseTake(models.Model):
student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='coursetake') #similar to reviews in the product class
course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='course')
grade = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = [['student', 'course']]
```

class SimpleCourseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Course
fields = ['title','credit_hours']

```
class CourseTakeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
course = SimpleCourseSerializer()
points = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
grade_points = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = CourseTake
    fields = ['id','course', 'grade', 'points', 'grade_points']

def get_points(self, coursetake: CourseTake):
    if coursetake.grade >= 90:
        return '4'
    elif coursetake.grade >= 70:
        return '3'
    elif coursetake.grade >= 50:
        return '2'
    return '1'

#TRY AND ERROR  
#Terminal: 'CourseTake' object has no attribute 'points'
def get_grade_points(self, coursetake: CourseTake):
    return coursetake.course.credit_hours * coursetake.points
```

I want to calculate grade points, which will be used later to calculate each student's GPA score. So the get_grade_point()  will return the credit_hours *  points. My problem is that the points field is not part of the model or serializer. I created a function to calculate the points for each course. Because I defined the points, Django keeps saying it's not an attribute anytime I try to access the point values. Is there a way to access the points value inside the get_grade_function?

[Image for better view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei4if.png)

Comment: can you share your models

Comment: I have done that. @ilyasbbu

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want I suggest to use
Save method on model

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

If you want to save result in database, Or you can use **@proparty** to make read only method also inside your model class if you don’t want to save it

After that you can use it easily in serializer

Comment: It's not working. If you look at the attached image, you can see that I've been able to add the points into the serializer. The problem here is that I'm unable to multiply the credit_hours * points (values) inside another function called grade_points. On the right hand side of the image is how I have populated the result. @Hashem

Comment: I will editing my answers to better solution

Answer (score 0):

The value of the grade point depends on the point, and since the point is not stored in the database, it is better to calculate them both in a function.
The amount of points is independent of the grade point

```
def et_grade_points(self, coursetake: CourseTake):
    if coursetake.grade >= 90:
        return coursetake.course.credit_hours * 4
    elif coursetake.grade >= 70:
        return coursetake.course.credit_hours * 3
    elif coursetake.grade >= 50:
        return coursetake.course.credit_hours * 2
    return coursetake.course.credit_hours 

def get_points(self, coursetake: CourseTake):
    if coursetake.grade >= 90:
        return '4'
    elif coursetake.grade >= 70:
        return '3'
    elif coursetake.grade >= 50:
        return '2'
    return '1'
```